# Keras: How to use fit_generator with 2 input images which corresponds to single output Image

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, generator

I'm creating a CNN and I want to use as input a picture high 40, weight 120, and 2 channels, and on the output high 40, weight 120, and 1 channel

```py
def generate_data_generator_for_two_images(genX1, genX2, genY):
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next() #input img1
        X2i = genX2.next() #input img2
        Y = genY.next() #Lable (output)
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], Y[0]

    train_inimggen = train_inimggen.flow_from_directory(train_closeconv_dir, target_size=(40, 120), color_mode='grayscale',
                                                    class_mode=None,
                                                    seed=250, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)
    train_gradimggen = train_gradimggen.flow_from_directory(train_grad_dir, target_size=(40, 120), color_mode='grayscale',
                                                        class_mode=None,
                                                        seed=250, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)
    train_finalimggen = train_finalimggen.flow_from_directory(train_final_dir, target_size=(40, 120),
                                                          color_mode='grayscale', class_mode=None,
                                                          seed=250, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)


    gen_flow = generate_data_generator_for_two_images(train_inimggen, train_gradimggen, train_finalimggen)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit_generator(gen_flow, steps_per_epoch=2, epochs=5)
```

I am not getting the desired output. Getting following error.

Error Message - tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.invalidargumenterror: incompatible shapes: [40,40,120] vs [40,120,1]

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace as text (in a code block), not as image.

Comment: Error Message - tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.invalidargumenterror: incompatible shapes: [40,40,120] vs  [40,120,1]